# How to Create several files from a list in a text file?

Tags: bash

Say I have a list in a file which contains filenames (without spaces):

```
filename
othername
somethingelse
...
```

- Each line followed by a CR, One "filename" per line

Is there some kind of touch script I can use to create hundreds of files with titles set by a list?

It would also be incredibly helpful if I could fill each file with content upon creation.

Any bashers have any tips: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04

Thanks

Comment: A GUI like this would be the bees knees, but for Ubuntu (I have not yet tried this with wine, but it isn't free so it is on the bottom of my totry list: http://www.sobolsoft.com/createfiletext/

Comment: How are the titles in a list? Post example input and output, please.

Comment: What do you mean by "a list in a text file"? A text file containing all the names of the files to be created?

Comment: where will the content come from? Do you want junk data, or does content= valid mp4 files or ??? Good luck.

Comment: just one liner text lines followed by a CR

Comment: The content I'd like to include is something like this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/com_aac_cachemate_demo_cachemate" />
</selector>` With the @drawable/ being the only variable. Thanks

Comment: (solution) Answered below in the second part of @Aaron's response!

Comment: Could there be spaces in the filenames? If not, I suggest we edit the question to explicitly state that the file_full_of_file_names will have *exactly one filename per line*.

Comment: For me, no. This is for an Android XML so the only allowed characters are limited "_" only and not starting with a number...alpha/numeric otherwise accepted. I have updated accordingly, I think. Thanks. Read my last comment on the solution below. Should I start a new question for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To simply create the files, assuming that `file_full_of_files_names` is a text file with whitespace-delimited filenames:

```
cat file_full_of_files_names | xargs touch
```

To actually fill them with content first, from a file called `initial_content`:

```
cat file_full_of_files_names | tr ' \t' '\n\n' | while read filename; do
    if test -f "$filename"; then
       echo "Skipping \"$filename\", it already exists"
    else
       cp -i initial_content "$filename"
    fi
done
```

Comment: There was an inconsistency. In the first version, you could put all the filenames on one line, separated by whitespace. The second version didn't allow that.

Comment: Should I post a new question extending this? I'm now wondering if I can change the @drawable/"XYZ" variable with the file name of each file created?

Comment: You could replace `cp -i initial_content "$filename"` with `sed -re "s/@drawable[^"]*/@drawable$filename/g" < initial_content > "$filename"`. But please note I have not tested this change.

Comment: Okay, cool. I have also posted the extended question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599070/bash-and-script-help-generating-files-with-variable-content and will add your comment as a comment there.