# Bash and Script help generating files with variable content

Tags: bash, cat

Extending this question: [How to Create several files from a list in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598741/how-to-create-several-files-from-a-list-in-a-text-file)

Summary:

```
cat file_full_of_files_names | tr ' \t' '\n\n' | while read filename; do
if test -f "$filename"; then
echo "Skipping \"$filename\", it already exists"
else
   cp -i initial_content "$filename"
fi
done
```

works great for what I want, but I'd like to extend it. The content below is what is found in 'initial_content'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/com_aac_cachemate_demo_cachemate" /> </selector>
```

I'd like to change the

```
@drawable/"XYZ"
```

XYZ variable to the name of the file created using the content from

```
initial_content
```

but with the XYZ variable filled in with the filenames from

```
file_full_of_file_names
```

content.

Any script kiddies? Bashers? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could replace `cp -i initial_content "$filename"` with `sed -re "s/@drawable[^"]*/@drawable$filename/g" < initial_content > "$filename"`. But please note I have not tested this change. – Aaron McDaid *Cross posted comment from referenced thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598741/how-to-create-several-files-from-a-list-in-a-text-file*

Comment: Once you have created some sample files from your initial_content, you can use `awk` to replace the XYZ with filename. Don't know if that's what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `AWK` instead of `cp`:

```
cat file_full_of_files_names | tr ' \t' '\n\n' | while read filename; do
if test -f "$filename"; then
echo "Skipping \"$filename\", it already exists"
else
   awk -F"/" -v OFS="/" -v name="$filename" '/@drawable/{sub(/.*/,name"\"",$2);print;next}1' < initial_content > "$filename"

fi
done
```

#### Test:

```
jaypal:~/Temp] cat file # Sample File
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/com_aac_cachemate_demo_cachemate" /> </selector>

[jaypal:~/Temp] echo $filename # Variable Initialization
name

[jaypal:~/Temp]  awk -F"/" -v OFS="/" -v name="$filename" '/@drawable/{sub(/.*/,name"\"",$2);print;next}1' file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/name"/> </selector>
[jaypal:~/Temp] 


[jaypal:~/Temp] filename="jaypal" # Re-initializing variable

[jaypal:~/Temp]  awk -F"/" -v OFS="/" -v name="$filename" '/@drawable/{sub(/.*/,name"\"",$2);print;next}1' file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/jaypal"/> </selector>
```

Comment: That helps, but it doesn't in fact change the content after `@drawable/` to the filename, it leaves it untouched. I'll play around with it and report back if successful. Thanks

Comment: I added a test. It did show that it worked and replaced the "XYZ" to "name".

Comment: Where are you getting `[jaypal:~/Temp] filename="jaypal"` ?  I want it to pull that information on its own.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was getting this error without realizing it: `awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file` `fold_yo623 `> fold_yo623.new' for reading (No such file or directory)` although the files are there just not being merged by awk into `.new`

Comment: I can't write the error with this short code: so here it is without the `code` emboss: awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `fold_yo623 > fold_yo623.new' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: Great! That works as expected. Wonderful help. Thanks for the knowledge and the quick cheat in the meantime ;-)

Comment: No worries. After reading the error I realized that you were using the older code. Glad it worked out. :)

Comment: Maybe you should edit the "haven't tested it" because now you have, and I have, and we know it works. Thanks again.